# Exceeding limts in Email sending in salesforce

Tags: email, batch

I have a requirement that, Need to update some bulk contact records and send an email to particular contact when contact gets updated using batch class. To achieve this, i created following class

```
Global class BatchExampleonContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global String query;
    global String field;
    global String value_to_change;

    global BatchExampleonContact(String query, String field, String value_to_change) {

        this.query = query;
        this.field = field;
        this.value_to_change = value_to_change;
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return database.getQueryLocator(query);

    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
        for(sObject s: scope) {
            //s.put(field, value_to_change);
            contact c = (contact)s;
            c.Description = value_to_change;
            con.add(c);
        }
        update con;
    } 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String[] toAddresses= new String[]{};
        List<contact> cons = Database.query(query);
        for(contact c: cons){
            toAddresses.add(c.Email);
            System.debug('toAddresses'+toAddresses);
        }
        AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, 
                          TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        System.debug(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Batch apex Job Completed ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
                         ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

}
```

While coming to update the record, Its working(Record getting updating) good. But, the email is not going to particular contact if email count is more than 10 emails if we call the class for the first time in the day. Mails are not going if we call class second time in the day and it is giving the following error.

> First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded: []

**As my research in salesforce online i got to known that, We can not send emails to an external users not more than 10. We can send number of emails to internal users(Limit does not apply for internal users) in Developer edition. Of course i am also using same one.**

According my class i am thinking so, My class is getting external users not internal users.

If my estimation is correct, How can i overcome my problem, which means how to add contact emails to internal usage and how to send an email according to my scenario?

Please provide solution to my problem. But i need to send the emails using batch class only.

Thanking you.

Comment: Your code is sending email to every possible contact processed by batch and not to  a particular contact as per your description. Do you need to send email to every contact processed by batch.

Comment: @Mukesh Verma, 
Yeah. I need to send email to every contact processed by batch.

Comment: As per salesforce Docs 'You can specify up to 100 recipients for the To field and up to 25 recipients for the CC and BCC fields in each SingleEmailMessage'.   It seems email limit is getting hit because number of contacts entering batch are more than hundred.

Comment: @Mukesh Verma, I have only 36 contacts in my org

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending emails to Contact so you should use `setTargetObjectId`

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String[] toAddresses= new String[]{};
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        List<contact> cons = Database.query(query);
        for(contact c: cons){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);

        mail.setSubject('Batch apex Job Completed ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
                         ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
        allMails.add(mail);  
     }
       Messaging.sendEmail(allMails)

}
```

This will not count as Internal limit. But if you have 100+ contacts you need to break this code.

Comment: +1, there is one more limitation that we can send only 1000 email per day in sandbox. same like in production as well.  if we send email to user then this limit doesn't count.

Comment: @Ratan Thanks. I am not sure this limit apply with contact

Comment: I am getting the same exception. 
`First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 4; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded: []`

Comment: Please observe my post. I am using Developer Edition....

Comment: @KSKumaar in developer org you can send only 15 email per day and in sandbox you can send 1000 emails per day.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm if the targetobjectId is contact

Comment: @KSKumaar As of now you have hit your daily limit so I think the only option you have for now is wait for 24 hours. But I am still not sure because when we use `setTargetObjectId` I never get this exception. I hope you are using this and remove the ` mail.setToAddresses` from your code.

Comment: So @Ratan As in the provided link by you, It is saying **You can send an unlimited amount of email to your org’s internal users, which includes portal users.**
Can you clearly explain it, which org can applicable for the above sentence


Is it applicable for Dev org?

Comment: @ Tushar Sharma, I did not used `setToAddresses` method. Even though it is giving same error. If it is by Not more than by 15 mails. Then it might be the answer

Comment: Finally, One question We can not send more than 15 emails in developer organization even the mails are from external users or internal users?
Is this correct?

Comment: @KSKumaar if the user is internal like user object records then this limit doesn't apply on user records

Comment: Okay @Ratan, Does My problem have any solution recording to developer Edition.? Sorry for Keep asking question....

Comment: @KSKumaar yes. this is kind of related to different limits that apply on different type of orgs( developer, sandbox and production org.)

Comment: @KSKumaar I think in this case you need to use WF email alert. Use a checkbox field and update it to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

To bulikfy your single email message.

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
//now do your loop
    .... {

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(emailsLeads);
       // mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
        String subject='GoToMeeting Invitation Details for '+subject;
        String body='test'; 
        mail.setHtmlBody(body); 
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        allMails.add(mail);
 ....
 }
//Finished your loop? Now you have an array of mails to send.
//This uses 1 of your 10 calls to sendEmail that you are allowed
Messaging.sendEmail(allMails);
```

Comment: Hi @Shravan, 
In this mail.setToAddresses(emailsLeads), How can i add emailsLeads, I mean using array of String or List of String?

Comment: @Ks Kumaar, go with your existing logic. String[] toAddresses= new String[]{};

Comment: This is the error which i am getting if we follows above one
Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way by which you can write finish method without hitting the limit:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, 
                      TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<contact> cons = Database.query(query);
    for(contact c: cons){
      if(c.Email!=null){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();      
         List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        sendTo.add(c.Email);
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setSubject('Batch apex Job Completed ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
                     ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');        
        mails.add(mail);
        }
    }

    if(mails.size()>0)
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

This logic creates a list of separate email to every contact and sends them all together.

Comment: This is the error which i am facing again 
`First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 4; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded: []`